# Can't cd into directory I just created in batch file

Tags: build-automation

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lastFolder=-1
for /d %%d in (1.0.0.*) do (
   set folder=%%d
   set folder=!folder:1.0.0.=!
   if not defined folder set folder=0
   if !folder! gtr !lastFolder! set lastFolder=!folder!
)
set /A nextFolder=lastFolder+1
mkdir 1.0.0.%nextFolder%
cd C:\Users\test\1.0.0.%nextFolder%
```

This batch file generates a new folder incremented by one every  time the batch file is called. It correctly generates the folder as I want, but I don't know why I can't cd into the folder through the batch file. If I cd manually to the folder I created in the batch file in the command prompt, it works just fine. Any help appreciated

Comment: On closer inspection, I added a mkdir command right after to see if I was in the directory that I cd into and it created in the 1.0.0.0 folder, but when I type dir, it shows me still only in the test directory. I'm confounded by this

Answer (score 0):

I would make the last line:

```
cd 1.0.0.%nextFolder%
```

Comment: In which way did it not work? What happened to make you think it did not change folders to the right place?